# Mollification with prescribed boundary values

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose you are given a $C^1$-function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ which restricts to a smooth function $f|_{\partial B}:\partial B\to \mathbb R$, where $B$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Can one construct a sequence of $C^\infty$-functions $g_n:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ such that $g_n=f$ on $\partial B$ for every $n$ and such that $g_n$ converges in the $C^1$-norm to $f$ or is there an obvious reason why this can't be found? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_n$ be any sequence of $C^\infty$ functions converging to $f$. Let $q_n$ be any sequence of $C^\infty$ functions such that $q_n=f$ and $\partial q_n/\partial n$ converges
to $\partial f/\partial n$ on $\partial B$. Let $\phi_n$ be a $C^\infty$ cutoff function with support contracting towards $\partial B$. Finally, let $g_n=\phi_nq_n+(1-\phi_n)p_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for!